# How can I print total

Tags: java

so I am trying to print the prime numbers between 1 and 100, and the total prime numbers in that range. I know the total prime numbers between 1 and 100 is 25, but I can't think of how to print it out in Java. It keeps printing 71?!?

Thank you for your help.

```
public class Chap6_Homework2 {
    public static void main (String [] args) {
        int i;
        int maxprime = 100;
        boolean isPrime = true;
        String foundprimenumbers = "";

        for (i = 2; i <= maxprime; i++) {
            isPrime = PrimeNumbers(i);
            if (isPrime) {
                foundprimenumbers = foundprimenumbers + i + " ";
            }
        }   
    System.out.println("Prime numbers are " + foundprimenumbers);   
    System.out.println("There are " + foundprimenumbers.length() + " prime numbers found.");
    }

    public static boolean PrimeNumbers(int foundprime) {
        for (int i = 2; i <= foundprime / 2; i++) {
            if (foundprime % i == 0) {
                return false;
            } 
        }
        return true;

    }



}
```

Comment: You are creating a `71` character `String` with `foundprimenumbers`. `foundprimenumbers = foundprimenumbers + i + " ";`  - beyond that, your question is unclear.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment. So there are 25 prime numbers in the range from 1 to 100. How can I calculate it?

Comment: What do you mean "calculate it"? You want to count the number of primes? `foundprimenumbers++;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change to

```
int foundprimenumbers = 0;

for (i = 2; i <= maxprime; i++) {
      if (PrimeNumbers(i)) {
        System.out.println(i);
        foundprimenumbers++;
      }
}   
// System.out.println("Prime numbers are " + foundprimenumbers);   
System.out.println("There are " + foundprimenumbers + " prime numbers found.");
```

where you print the prime number immediately and the count of primnumbers is stored in an `int` variable

Comment: OMG. Thank you so much. I was trying to print all the prime numbers on the same line with spaces between them, and that is where I got messed up. Thank you so muchhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh.

Comment: If you want all on the same line you can either use `System.out.print` or append to a StringBuilder and then print later, but the counting is seperate